# Rspec testing for duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to test for "A product can list users that have reviewed it without duplicates"

this is what my test looks like

product_spec.rb

```
describe Product do

let!(:product) { Product.create } 
.
.#other test
.

  it "can list users that review it without duplicates" do
   product.reviews.create({user_id: 1, review: "test"})
  product.reviews.create({user_id: 1, review: "test2"})

   product.user.uniq.count.should eq(1)
  end
end
```

terminal result

```
1) Product can list users that review it without duplicates
 Failure/Error: product.reviews.create({user_id: 1, review: "test"})
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved:
   You cannot call create unless the parent is saved
 # ./spec/models/product_spec.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: product.save => boolean

Comment: You need to share more of your code, including anything involved in the creation of `product` in your test.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
product.save.reviews.create
```

Save returns boolean whether object has been saved successfully or not. You need to split this into two lines:

```
product.save
product.reviews.create
```

Comment: and I suggest to use `save!` and `create!` to catch if some records can not be saved because of validation issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a Review on a Product that hasn't been saved with:

```
product.reviews.create()
```

I'm guessing `product` isn't valid, thus it hasn't been saved by

```
let!(:product) { Product.create }
```

which simply returns the invalid object if `create` fails.

You should

1. Use `create!` to make sure you notice when saving the object fails (it'll raise an exception if there's a validation error).
2. Make sure your `Product` can be created with the data, you provide it.

Comment: you say : (it'll raise an exception instead of returning false), "create" don't return false if saving object fails, it return an invalid object model instead

Comment: Indeed. Corrected my answer.